# Broke xauth, stuck in login loop, no $DISPLAY env set

Tags: login, xorg

Yesterday I fiddled with Xauth because in my Steam client log there were some errors about not being able to authenticate with X:

`Could not connect to X session manager: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and <garbage>`

I was not able to resolve this, but I managed to break my login process. \o/

When I enter my password, it tries to switch to my user session, then returns back to the login screen.

I found a workaround by switching to terminal and doing this:

```
> DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY
> xauth list
> xauth add $DISPLAY . <hexkey from xauth list>
```

When I then switch back to the gui and do login, it works.

It's worth to note that DISPLAY is not set when I do the terminal stuff and I think that this is the problem. I cannot remember to have changed anything to remove the DISPLAY env and I think it should be set by X, but it is no longer. I'm not sure if I need to do the `xauth add ...` thing or if just setting the DISPLAY env is already enough - have to try that out.

The output of `xauth list` before I do anything is like this:

```
myhost/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE  2b3996b81997d587e6f7f4348a11df3d
```

After I do login, it looks like this:

```
myhost/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  c71526c38a544cb15dc15875a4992486
myhost/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE  2b3996b81997d587e6f7f4348a11df3d
```

I'm using Xfce for desktop and lightdm as the login manager, my system is a Xubuntu 19.10.

Any idea how I can fix this? :|
Thank you very much!

Edit:

According to my bash_history, these are the commands I have executed:

```
ls ~/.Xauthority -la
xauth list
echo $DISPLAY
xauth list
xauth add $DISPLAY - `mcookie`
xauth list
mcookie
xauth --help
xauth remove $DISPLAY - `mcookie`
xauth list
xauth add $DISPLAY "MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE" `mcookie`
xauth list
xauth list|grep `uname -n`
xauth extract - $ DISPLAY | sudo -iu steam xauth merge -
```

`.Xauthority` belongs to my user and group and it has permission 0600.
All commands were executed as my user, not root.
I *think* it works with my workaround because I add a MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1?

Comment: Have you tried simply deleting (or renaming) the (possibly messed up) `~/.Xauthority` file?

Comment: No I have not. And that actually fixed it, thank you very much!! :) 
What now, do I answer my own question or do you post a solution I then can accept?

Comment: Feel free to post your own solution - you will be able to accept it after a small delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by steeldriver, the solution was to deleted the messed up `~/.Xauthority` file. After doing that and rebooting, everything went back to normal.